# ubuntu repository for libpng

Tags: ubuntu, repository, libpng

I need to upgrade libpng to libpng14 in ubuntu 10.0.

do you know a suitable repository ?

how can I add it my sources.list?

regards

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It should probably be on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 0):

I know a ppa repository for 1.5
But you mentioned "upgrade" so I think you need libpng greater or equal 1.4
Try this one:
https://launchpad.net/~hanmac/+archive/ppa/+packages